Rav Moshe Feinstein Didn't Sell Chametz For Non-Businesses?
Rav Moshe Feinstein reportedly wrote in a teshuvah that he did not sell chametz for people except in the case of a business because he was opposed to selling chametz. Where is this written in the Igros Moshe? (The Mesores Moshe says in multiple seforim that Rav Moshe preferred not selling chametz gamur, but saying they did not go so far to say he did not sell chametz for non-businesses.)

https://outorah.org/p/33326/#:~:text=Rav%20Moshe%20Feinstein%20confirmed%20the,avail%20themselves%20of%20this%20option

"reportedly" Where did you see this reported?
